# Can I iterate through each of my SharedObjects in ActionScript 3?

Tags: actionscript, shared-objects

Is it possible to execute a "foreach" through each of my SharedObjects?

Something like this . . .

```
_so = SharedObject.getLocal("test","/");
foreach (var item:Object in _so)
{
    // print key name and value
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure I understand.
1.Do you want to loop through all your Shared Objects ?
2.Do you want to loop through all your objects inside the data property of a SharedObject ?

1.Assuming sharedObjects is an array containing SharedObject instances

```
var sharedObjects:Array = ['test','fred','louie'];
var sharedObjectsData:Array = [];

for(var i:int = 0 ; i < sharedObjects.length ; i++){
sharedObjectsData.push(SharedObject.getLocal(sharedObjects[i],"/").data);
}
```

//or something like that

2.Try using an old school [for in](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flash/9.0/ActionScriptLangRefV3/statements.html#for..in) loop.

```
for(var i in _so.data){
trace('property: ' + i + ' value: ' + _so.data[i]);
}
```

Hope it helps!